WordPress user password reset not working
I have additional users set up on my WordPress site. One of the other users has asked me to reset their password as the 'forgot my password' function doesn't work (a reset password email isn't delivered). I have edited their profile to set a new password, but the new password doesn't work. I've tried this several times with no success. If anyone has a solution I'd appreciate it.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Do other emails work from the site? Do you mean the password doesn't work when you try it yourself?

Check the error.log files in site root and wp-admin folder for any clues.
It's also possible a plugin is interfering with the mail() command - maybe one that changes the login?
You could temp disable all plugins and then try the password reset process. If it works then, enable plugins one at a time to find the culprit.

I think you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-logging/ to see what error is thrown when email password reset is sent from your website.
